# No email from Single Email Message

Tags: email, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

We've been using "SingleEmailMessage" many times and all of a sudden when using it on a new class, the emails are not being received.  I check the debug logs and I see "SingleEmailMessage" executes and with no errors; I tried using emails in other classes we use "SingleEmailMessage" and still no email received.

Also, if I was getting a governor limit, would the call fail to "SingleEmailMessage"? But I'm not getting any error.

Did something new get introduced in recent release that affects "SingleEmailMessage" that I might be missing?

Comment: Can you check Email Deliveribility settings and select All Emails and test it

Comment: @SantanuBoral Thanks! Yeah, I checked that already and "All Emails" is set.   I wonder though if there is something on the Email Deliverability for "All Emails" that might be causing the issue.  Is there something here I should enable/disable?

Comment: can you compile the class in previous version and check if that works